# Equivalences in Model Categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, ct.category-theory

If $\mathcal M$ is a model category and I know that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal M)$, is it guaranteed that there is a zig-zag of weak-equivalences in $\mathcal M$ connecting $A$ and $B$?

Comment: In particular, you could have searched http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22zig-zag%22+weak+equivalence&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 .  If you click the top link, it has the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The isomorphism in $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ is represented by a morphism in $\mathcal{M}$ from a cofibrant replacement for $A$ to a fibrant replacement for $B$.  The "converse to the Whitehead lemma" states that a map in a model category is a weak equivalence iff its image in the homotopy category is an isomorphism.  Combining this with the definition of (co)fibrant replacement, we see that $A$ and $B$ are connected by a 3-step zig-zag of weak equivalences.